# .htaccess and URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a program `a.php`. It takes 2 strings: `a` and `b` (which doesn't have any `_` inside), and a float number. The number can be omitted with a default value.

What's wrong with the following rule?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_([^_]+)\.htm$ a.php?f=$1&t=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_([^_]+)\.htm#([0-9.]+)$ a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3 [NC]
```

Thank you.

Comment: What URLs are you using and what is actually not working?

Comment: i am trying to use the url of A_B.htm or A_B.htm#C

Comment: i have form call a.php with 3 parameters. i am able to use the following rewrite rule, and a_b.htm/c does work.

{ RewriteRule ^(.*)_([^]+).htm/([0-9.]+)$ a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3 [NC] } 

however, my problem is when the user click a sumit button on the form, i still see 
a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3

how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RewriteRule
>   ^(.*)*([^*]+).htm#([0-9.]+)$
>   a.php?f=$1&t=$2&amt_from=$3 [NC]

Are you getting a 500 error? if so you should note that # is a comment, and the rest of your code isn't being parsed

Comment: Hmm, maybe that's the problem since my error was $3 never working

Comment: You should note that # (used for javascript/anchors) is CLIENT side, and php/htaccess will not read this (which is server side)

Comment: you are right. thanks a lot. after i change the #, it rocks! ty

Comment: Remember to choose upvote/choose as correct for answers which helped your question